# Openstack CLI windows throws "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: openstack

I have followed the instructions in the Openstack Documentation [here](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/user-guide/common/cli-install-openstack-command-line-clients.html) to install the openstack CLI. When I was done installing Python 2.7.18 and python-openstackclient, I ran the command `openstack` in powershell and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\openstack-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('python-openstackclient==5.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'openstack')()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\openstackclient\shell.py", line 22, in <module>
    from osc_lib.api import auth
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\osc_lib\api\auth.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keystoneauth1.identity.v3 import k2k
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\keystoneauth1\identity\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from keystoneauth1.identity import generic
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\keystoneauth1\identity\generic\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from keystoneauth1.identity.generic.password import Password  # noqa
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\keystoneauth1\identity\generic\password.py", line 16, in <module>
    from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\keystoneauth1\identity\v3\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keystoneauth1.identity.v3.oauth2_client_credential import *  # noqa
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\keystoneauth1\identity\v3\oauth2_client_credential.py", line 119
    headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {oauth2_token}'
```

I inspected the file and saw the line it's complaining about. After a quick google, I saw that it was reported and fixed in 2022 as you can see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/keystoneauth/+bug/1999431). Then I ran command `pip install --upgrade python-openstackclient` to update the package to latest, but I am still getting the same error. I downloaded and install `python 3` (Although Openstack documentation says: Currently, the clients do not support Python 3.) to see if maybe there was a package dependency on it, but the results are the same.

I see in the PR [here](https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/keystoneauth/+/867603), there as a change made to the `setup.cfg` file, but I am unable to find a file with that name in my local files where the libraries are installed to confirm I have the latest. Could anyone offer any guidance on how to resolve this issue? is there a step missing in the openstack documentation that I should be aware of? I am assuming after installing the packages I shouldn't have to go in and modify any files.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only.  Questions about deploying / installing, administering and using OpenStack should be asked on ServerFault; https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently, the clients do not support Python 3.

This is incorrect.  You are reading the OSC documentation from the Newton release.  It is 7+ years out of date ... and not applicable to the latest versions of OpenStack.

How do I know?

1. I do OpenStack programming in python 3 every day ... including using many of the client OS python clients.
2. The last line of stacktrace shows this line of code:

   ```
   headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {oauth2_token}'
   ```

   That is using f-string syntax that was first introduced in Python 3.6.

In fact, the stacktrace is happening **because** you are running python 3.6+ code on python 2.7.

And one more piece of evidence is [this page](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Python3#OpenStack_clients) which lists the Python 3 status of all of the openstack python client libraries.

---

My advice: read the [latest documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/2023.1/) and start again with a clean python 3 install.  And more generally, always check that you are using the correct version of the OpenStack documentation ... not just the version the Google finds for you first.

Notes:

- You typically need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` to install into a python3 installation.  Though that depends on how you installed Python.
- I recommend installing and using `virtual-env` for your OpenStack work so that the dependencies installed with the OpenStack don't mess up things for other unrelated python applications.

Comment: Thank you, I just upgraded to Python 3.* and it now works, I had not idea I was looking at outdated documentation and the link I provided was one of the first links that came up on google when I looked up `openstack CLI documentation`

Answer (score 1):

Just stick to py3.

The Openstack CLI is clearly using py3 on my box, and it works fine, although I didn't install it from source, using a pre-packaged version:

```
[zaitcev@lebethron tmp]$ which openstack
/usr/bin/openstack
[zaitcev@lebethron tmp]$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/openstack
python3-openstackclient-6.0.0-2.fc38.noarch
[zaitcev@lebethron tmp]$ head -3 /usr/bin/openstack
#!/usr/bin/python3
# PBR Generated from 'console_scripts'

[zaitcev@lebethron tmp]$
```

If you could point out where the docs say that py3 is not supported, it could help to correct it, too.